# Which is the best approach to edit and save data from a smart-table (angular 1.5)?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm new to angular, and I want to load and update data form restful services. The json response is an array with about 2000 records, so I use smart-table for pagination, filtering, and sorting, along with xeditable for inline editing.

My problem is that I don't know how detect if a row has changes so I can do a save request.

How can I detect which row has changed from my smart-table so I can do an update request?

Comment: go over the docs, the last couple of examples are just what you need.

Comment: thanks, I found what I needed in the xeditable docs, using directive "onaftersave" made the deal, I needed something like .. 

  <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onaftersave="updateUser()">
    {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
  </a>